# Add "Bugs must be reported on drupal.org" as close reason

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

When there are issues like [Metatag images don't work anymore after updating to Drupal 8.6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/269708/15055) I tend to close-vote them and giving `off-topic because ... > Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers ...` as closing reason. Which doesn't really fit. But there's no other reason that comes close to the actual reason.

As this happens quite often, can we add another closing reason?

Or should we tag them with `Other` and specify?

---

In the screenshot below I just quickly edited the current dialogue to give you an idea what I think might work:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All SE sites are allowed three custom close reasons.  Our current ones are

- Questions on **programming, PHP, SQL, etc.** that do not relate directly to Drupal are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).
- This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced, was solved by a cache clear, or was a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.
- Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I do think that is a good reason, but we would need to pick one of these to retire.

Comment: There isn't any need to retire a closing reason that still applies for new questions. If 3 custom closing reasons aren't enough, we can request to add an extra closing reason, but it must considered that users can use custom closing reasons by their own.

Comment: @kiamlaluno — So, mpdonadio might be wrong? And we could try to request a fourth custom closing reason? Do I understand this right? Do you mind adding an answer about how this theoretically could be accomplished? About the whole procedure maybe...