# Community-related closing reasons for 2020

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

It is time we reevaluate the community-related closing reasons (previously called custom closing reasons) that Drupal Answers is using. Right now, we have two custom reasons.

> Questions on **programming, PHP, SQL, etc.** that do not relate directly to Drupal are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced, was solved by a cache clear, or was a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

The third reason previously used has been retired because it was being misapplied a lot.

> Questions asking to recommend or find a book, tool, module, theme, distribution, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

We can have three custom close reasons.

Based on the questions that we are seeing, what would be three good reasons?

Please post one reason per answer with justification, and vote up/down. Based on votes, we can figure out the next steps.

See also [Custom off-Topic reasons for Drupal Anwers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2477/custom-off-topic-reasons-for-drupal-anwers).

Comment: I'd definitely like to preserve `recommend module, theme, distribution` somehow. And also this sentence in the end `instead describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it`. I need to think about it a bit. 

Comment: I'd also like to see that one return @leymannx, but perhaps with different wording that would help people to apply it more correctly. I've also never thought that _tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_ was the right phrasing anyway. I feel like that should be more like _tend to attract answers containing only a link, with no explanation in the answer about how the link can be used to solve the problem_. I think that better captures what we're objecting to. Bit wordy maybe

Comment: I think that off-topic is too broad and all-encompassing because it ranges from "recommend a module" to "link me to the documentation page (or video)". I've used it as a sort of catch-all to help close low-research/effort questions. However what leymannx mentioned, "instead describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it" could also be added to the Needs focus or Needs details close questions. If we instead changed "recommend module" to "Needs focus" then this off-topic could soley be about documentation/tutorial link requests.

Comment: @mradcliffe Unfortunately, we can't change the focus/details ones. Those are the standard system ones. Personally, I don't like the way they got reworded from the old unclear/too-broad.

Comment: We should also consider the default closing reasons changed and decide if they already cover our previous custom reasons, or we need custom reasons for very specific questions they keep getting asked.

Comment: @Clive With that description, a question asking for a module and adding "give a link to the project page on drupal.org and your opinion about the module" would be fine just because it's not asking just for a link.

Comment: @mradcliffe It's not too broad: It's making examples of _link to off-site resources_. It should also be used when that is what the question is asking, not when to answer it I give a link to an off-site resource.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure that's not the right text specifically @kiamlaluno, I was more just bringing up that I think the previous text didn't quite capture the intent of the close reason either

Comment: @Clive I think that saying _Questions that are **expressly** asking for […]_ could avoid the closing reason is used when the users **think** the question is asking for module recommendation.

Comment: Yeah I like that @kiamlaluno, makes sense

Comment: @mpdonadio Me either. Now, the _too broad_ one seems more focused on _asking a single question_. I guess that the old _too broad_ is now _needs more details_.

Comment: I edited the question because _This question does not appear to be about Drupal within the scope defined in the help center._ isn't a closing reason users can select, but a sentence the system shows when users selected two closing reasons.

Comment: I'm starting to get used to the absent custom close reasons. Only sometimes I use the "other specify" reason for bug reports or support requests to third-party projects. Sometimes I miss the "can no longer be reproduced" but even this can quickly be typed in "other specify".

Answer (score 3):

I already [asked for the bug report close reason in 2018](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3724/15055) and really want it to be in the list. But, I think the recommendation close reason is a little bit more important. But you do the voting so here comes a bug report close reason.

> This is a bug report or support request to a third-party project hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and must be reported in its issue queue to track issues in a single place, not here.

Comment: Keep in mind we have just 3 custom closing reasons. With the three reasons you listed, it would mean that questions asking to find or recommend off-site resources would be on-topic.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – I know, I know. Just typing up the module recommendation one. I just didn't want to have the bug report one to be unmentioned. Though in the end when weighing up bug report and module recommendation I'd rather have bug reports to be typed manually under "other, specify".

Answer (score 3):

Now the problematic one. It has been misapplied a lot. Probably for questions that didn't show minimal effort and should better be flagged as "needs details or clarity" or "needs more focus". Nevertheless questions merely asking to find a module are quite a problem. So I'd throw this one in the ring again.

I'm adding the small word **explicitly**, explicitly asking to recommend. I've shortened the listing. And I rephrased the explanation in a way implying that the most problematic thing with these questions is that using a search engine and testing modules out is something that should be done by OP themselves.

> Questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers. Research and testing needs to be done before asking a question. Please describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I had to google the definition of "expressly". IMO would be better if it said `Questions explicitly asking to recommend, ...`

Comment: @NoSssweat – Ah yeah, that's much better! I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep the second one **as-is**. This happens quite often and it's also a good close reason for outdated questions.

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced, was solved by a cache clear, or was a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's definitely keep the first. It's a good catch-all reason for questions where Drupal is more of a coincidence than the main problem. But I'd add **Twig** and **CSS** in the listing.

> Questions on **programming, PHP, SQL, Twig, CSS etc.** that do not relate directly to Drupal are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: To be a catch-all should also include those questions about server settings, which aren't Drupal-related.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – I thought the exact same, but didn't want to make the listing any longer. Do you have an idea how to put that in the listing? Or should there be another migration path to Webmasters SE maybe?

Comment: I would avoid suggesting a site in the closing reason, given that there are more sites that would suit. I would rather say _Questions on programming and server settings that aren't directly related to Drupal are off-topic here._ Instead of the site link there could be a link to a question on meta that explains exactly what _directly related_ means for us.

Comment: Also, I think that giving a link to a site just make users ask for us to migrate their questions to that site, or think that we are saying the question is surely on-topic for the other site. There are users who would take _can asked on_ as _it is surely a question for that site_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno – That are good points. I didn't think about the link. But indeed it's actually quite problematic. How do you think we proceed with feedback? Do you add another answer? Do I edit mine?

Comment: I added my answer, since it's different in more aspects. I am going to add my answers for the three closing reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this as one of the custom closing reasons.

> Questions on **programming, programming languages, server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** that don't require specific Drupal expertise to solve are off-topic here.

It would make clear the questions must be directly related to Drupal. It doesn't suggest any site to avoid it seems we are saying the question is surely on-topic for other sites.

(In my list of custom closing reasons, this would be shown as first one.)

Comment: I wonder if something like _that don't require specific Drupal expertise to solve_ might be better than _don't directly relate to Drupal_? I always found the latter a smidge ambiguous

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now that you make me think of that, I guess that for some users _I got this issue when doing something on a Drupal site_ is sufficient for the question to directly relate to Drupal.

Comment: I think this could also be improved by trying to add @leymannx's suggestion about bug reports. I agree with them that bug reports as well as documentation improvements should be reported upstream at drupal.org rather than getting lost in SE.

Comment: @mradcliffe That should be a different closing reason. This one is for those questions that even a user not knowing Drupal (which includes those users who has never used/tried Drupal) could answer, while the cases you describe do require Drupal expertise to answer them.

Comment: I think that these could be merged by merging the Drupal expertise portions, and thus save one of the precious Close options.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following closing reason for module recommendations.

> Questions **expressly asking to recommend, suggest, or find a module, theme, distribution/profile, tutorial, or other off-site resources** are off-topic here. Questions comparing two modules, themes, or distributions/profiles **could** be on-topic.

The closing reason says **expressely** because the closing reason should not be used if I think the question is asking for a module recommendation, or I think a module is the only possible answer. If a question doesn't make clear whether is asking for a module or code, it could be possibly closed using one of the default closing reasons.
I shorted the list, since **off-site resources** includes also, for example, books.

Answer (score 0):

> Questions asking to recommend, suggest, find, or report a problem with core, a module, theme, distribution/profile, tutorial, or other off-site resources are off-topic here. Questions comparing two modules, themes, or distributions/profiles could be on-topic.

This is [kiamlaluno's answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3821/42650), but without the word expressly because I think the closing reason should be used if I think the question is asking for a module recommendation or is best-suited for an off-site resource such as drupal.org.

I also added "report a problem with" and "core" because I think that helps to direct questions that may be bug or support requests back to those contributing on drupal.org.